# No Ethernet Device on Samsung Series 9 with mini Ethernet

Tags: 17.04, ethernet, samsung

Is there anything else to do if my ethernet interface is not found in `lshw` and `lspci`? I have Samsung NP900x3c and can't setup Ethernet with the mini Dongle. The router shows connection when I plug in the cable (visible as green light), but can't find a solution for Ubuntu..

`lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM75 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)
03:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 02)
```

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network                 
  description: Wireless interface
  product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
  vendor: Intel Corporation
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
  logical name: wlp1s0
  version: 24
  serial: c8:f7:33:17:f7:0f
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
  configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.10.0-40-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.1.65 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
  resources: irq:32 memory:f0600000-f0601fff
```

The output from `lsusb` is:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2232:1024 Silicon Motion 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Which could possibly mean that the mini LAN is actually USB, because there is only 2 physical USB slots: one usb2 and one usb3

Comment: Is the mini dongle a USB device? May we see: `lsusb` ?

Comment: @chili555 thanks a lot, that does seem like it could be possibility, included the output, thanks. What in that case?

Comment: It is not at all clear which is the ethernet dongle. Please detach it. Open a terminal and run:  `tail -f /var/log/syslog` Watch the terminal and insert the device. What does syslog report? Please edit your question to add the result. Get out of *tail* with Ctrl+c.

Comment: Nothing happens there :( .. the router LED at the cable turns green though (indicating the cable is plugged in) .. could this be the dongle fault? I just bought it. But considering there is no `eth0` device anywhere - it looks like it might not be the dongle fault.. thanks @chili555

Comment: In 17.04, the interface is likely not eth0. It will probably be enx...something. Do you see that in `ifconfig` ?

Comment: No, only `lo` and `wlp1s0`. Any other ideas?

Comment: Everything I've read suggests that it's plug and play; for instance: http://jtes.net/2012/03/23/samsung-series-9-2012-np900x3b/ Do you have another computer, even Windows, that you can try it on? I am suspicious that the dongle is faulty.